# glfwCreateWindow(..) returns null in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, graphic, glfw

I am using the GLFW and only want to open a empty windows.

I downloaded the GLFW for Windows 32.
Created an empty console project and wrote this code:

```
#include "main.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "glfw3dll")
#pragma comment (lib, "OpenGL32")

#define GLFW_DLL

#include <glfw3.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;


GLFWwindow* window;

bool running = true;


bool initialise(){
return true;
}

void update(double deltaTime){

}

void render(){

}



int main(int argc, char **argv) {

if (!glfwInit)
    return -1;

window = (glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Hello World", nullptr, nullptr));

if (window == nullptr){
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

if (!initialise()){
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

auto currentTimeStamp = system_clock::now();
auto prevTimeStamp = system_clock::now();

while (running)
{
    currentTimeStamp = system_clock::now();

    auto elapsed = duration_cast<milliseconds>(currentTimeStamp - prevTimeStamp);
    auto seconds = double(elapsed.count()) / 1000.0;

    update(seconds);

    render();

    glfwPollEvents();

    prevTimeStamp = currentTimeStamp;

}

glfwTerminate();

return -1;
}
```

And I think I added the library and the header correctly. 
But everytime the programm exits with -1 after the glfwCreateWindow(..) function, because this functions return null.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Could you properly indent your code please.

Comment: i think until the error, it just looks whether the glfw is initiated (glfwInit) and then it tries to create the window with the glfwCreateWindows(...) function, but that does not work...

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!glfwInit)
    return -1;
```

I'm not sure why `glfwInit` would be `NULL` unless something truly terrible happened during DLL load.

Try *calling* `glfwInit()` instead:

```
if( !glfwInit() )
    return -1;
```

Comment: ok, i've got it. but I started the whole project from the beginning. One issue was that I had the driver for my Radeon HD 4200 from the windows updater, when I installed the proprietary driver, it worked. Thanks man!